# Why is my exception not picked up by jquery ajax call to controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a button that calls an action in my asp.net mvc controller. I'm trying to catch errors and display them to the user in a decent way, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this properly. Whenever I force an exception (for testing purposes) in my controller, the .sucess part of my ajax call i still fired. Here's my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#del").on("click", function() {
        var message;
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("DeleteImage", "UnitSummary")",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { unitId: "@Model.UnitId" },
            error: function(msg) {
                message = msg;
                $('#delsection').hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Ouch!</strong> ' + message.statusText + '</div>').fadeIn('slow');
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                message = msg;
                $('#delsection').hide().html('<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Image was deleted.</div>').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

And here's my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteImage(int unitId)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Forced error");
        UnitClient.UpdateUnitImage(unitId, new byte[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(e);
        return Json(new { e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new JsonResult(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Sucess always gets called, even though the image is not deleted. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, you're catching the exception and returning the `JsonResult`. The result of the ajax call will always be `200` which is ok, that's why the `success` method gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever I force an exception (for testing purposes) in my controller,
>   the .sucess part of my ajax call i still fired.

The following line of code is not an exception that jQuery's `ajax` interprets as an error response from the server (hence no call to the `error` callback), ***but*** a regular `200 OK` response:

```
return Json(new { e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Do it like this instead:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
```

This is where HTTP status codes come into play, `BadRequest` is an HTTP error status code.

**Here's more about `BadRequest`:**

> Equivalent to HTTP status 400. BadRequest indicates that the request
>   could not be understood by the server. BadRequest is sent when no
>   other error is applicable, or if the exact error is unknown or does
>   not have its own error code.